# Community Awarded bounty Rep Not Given when own answer after bounty has higest votes

Tags: support, bounty-awards

This question
[Where and how to mention Stackoverflow participation in the résumé?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38597/where-and-how-to-mention-stackoverflow-participation-in-the-resume/63130)
I had started a bounty to get better direct answer to the question. The whole topic has much discussion on yes and no to putting the participation on resume with no real answers on where and how to mention. except a very few.

After the bounty had started 06:10 I had posted an answer to make it relevant on what kind of answer was expected for the bounty  .The newly [posted answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38597/where-and-how-to-mention-stackoverflow-participation-in-the-resume/63130#63130) was at 6:13. 
Over the week's duration this had got the highest votes.
Which should be given  Community awarded bounty i.e 50 rep. This has not happened.

I had checked the rules and similar post on meta regarding this and confirmed that the bounty should be awarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: you can't be awarded your own bounty.

Comment: It would be nice if this point is mentioned in the bounty FAQ. There is a difference between 1.Awarding bounty to own answer 2.Community awarding bounty to answer ( high votes ) which might happen to be yours.